# Robolectric start a fragment that has an observer

Tags: android, android-livedata, robolectric, android-unit-testing, android-fragmentscenario

How to start a fragment with a LiveData observer in the test scope with Robolectric

Fragment

```
class MyFragment(private val viewModel: MyViewModel) : Fragment() {

    ...

    fun myObserver {
        ... 
        // If I remove this observer the test will pass. 
        viewModel.MyLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My Test uses the RobolectricTestRunner so I can launch the fragment in the test scope.

```
@RunWith(robolectricTestRunner::class) 
class MyFragmentTest {

    // Executes tasks in the Architecture Components in the same thread
    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Test
    fun testOne() {
        val viewModel: MyViewModel = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(
            factory = MainFragmentFactory(viewModel),
            fragmentArgs = null
            themeResId = R.style.Theme_MyTheme
        )
        // Tried implementing shadowOf as the error suggests. 

    } 
}
```

I get the following error when trying to run the test. I've tried setting Main looper to idle before and after instantiating the FragmentScenario.

```
java.lang.Exception: Main looper has queued unexecuted runnables. This might be the cause of the test failure. You might need a shadowOf(getMainLooper()).idle() call.
```

I've tried the following

- implementing a shadow class for the Main Looper.  Annotating the class with Looper mode.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@LooperMode(LooperMode.Mode.PAUSED)
class MyFragmentTest {
```

- Adding scenario states

```
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
    scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
```

My Test dependencies.

```
    // Test
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.3'
    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.2"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.3"
    testImplementation 'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.5.1"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.28.2"

    // Testing Fragments
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.2"
```

Links I've used to find a solution'
[Testing LiveData Transformations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810330/testing-livedata-transformations)
https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2019/01/17/livedatajunit5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look into your repository on github [here](https://github.com/Shawn-Nichol/TDDScoreKeeper). Here's what I've found.

## Problem 1

Your first problem is that you mock out a `ViewModel`. So, when you simulate `onResume` for your `Fragment` it invokes:

```
fun liveDataObserver() {
    viewModel.scoreLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        // 
    } )
}
```

Since `viewModel` is mocked, `scoreLiveData` is `null` and you get an NPE.

To fix this, you also mock out `scoreLiveData` method so that it returns some acceptable result:

```
...
    val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = 3 }
    val viewModel = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
    doReturn(liveData).`when`(viewModel).scoreLiveData
...
```

This will fix your `testOne` completely, but not yet `testTwo`.

## Problem 2

It's related only to your `testTwo` method. The problem is that you're calling `liveDataObserver()` in your `also` block, and that is invoked before your `Fragment's` `viewLifecycleOwner` has been set in `onCreateView`:

```
...
    scenario = launchFragmentInContainer {
        MyFragment(viewModel).also {
            it.liveDataObserver()
        }
    } 
...
```

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to test here, but if you want to verify that you can start observing after `Fragment's` `View` has been created, you could do something as following:

```
    ...
    // make sure your Fragment is started
    scenario = launchFragmentInContainer (
        factory = MainFragmentFactory(viewModel),
        initialState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
    )
    // call liveDataObserver on it
    scenario.withFragment {
        this.liveDataObserver()
    }
```

## Full Code

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MyFragmentTest {
    private lateinit var scenario: FragmentScenario<MyFragment>

    @Test
    fun testOne() = runBlockingTest {
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = 1 }
        val viewModel = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
        doReturn(liveData).`when`(viewModel).scoreLiveData

        scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(
            factory = MainFragmentFactory(viewModel),
            fragmentArgs = null,
            themeResId = R.style.Theme_TDDScoreKeeper,
            initialState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
        )

        scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
        scenario.recreate() // Simulates if the phone ran low on resources and the app had to be recreated.
    }

    @Test
    fun testTwo() {
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = 1 }
        val viewModel = mock(MyViewModel::class.java)
        doReturn(liveData).`when`(viewModel).scoreLiveData

        scenario = launchFragmentInContainer(
            factory = MainFragmentFactory(viewModel),
            initialState = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
        )
        scenario.withFragment {
            this.liveDataObserver()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's better to mock `ViewModel` completely in this case. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Shawn Cool! In your case (if using a `mock` object), it doesn't really matter which pair you choose. It matters if you use  a `spy` method though..